# Integral by the given $u$-substitution

Tags: derivatives, indefinite-integrals, substitution

Original equation $$\int\sqrt{e^t-5}dt \qquad u=\sqrt{e^t-5}$$
This is what I've done so far$$\int{u}dt$$ $$du=\frac{e^t}{2\sqrt{e^t-5}}dt$$$$dt=\frac{2\sqrt{e^t-5}}{e^t}du$$$$\int{u}{\frac{2\sqrt{e^t-5}}{e^t}}du$$ From this point on what would i need to do?

Comment: You need to put *everything* in terms of the new variable $u$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice,  let $e^t-5=u^2\implies e^tdt=2udu$ $$dx=\frac{2udu}{u^2+5}$$
$$\int\sqrt{e^t-5}dt=\int u\frac{2udu}{u^2+5}$$
$$=2\int \frac{u^2du}{u^2+5}$$ $$=2\int \frac{u^2+5-5du}{u^2+5}$$
$$=2\int \frac{u^2+5du}{u^2+5}-10\int \frac{du}{u^2+5}$$
$$=2\int du-10\int \frac{du}{u^2+5}$$ $$=2u-10\frac{1}{\sqrt 5}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{u}{\sqrt 5}\right)+C$$
$$=2\sqrt{e^t-5}-2\sqrt 5\tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{e^t-5}{5}}\right)+C$$

Comment: May I ask why it is you have the +5-5 in $2\int\frac{u^2+5-5}{u^2+5}du$?

Comment: alright, notice $$u^2=u^2+5-5$$

Comment: Sorry, but I still do not understand.

Comment: $u^2=u^2+5-5$ is assumed for making partial fractions just as you edited in the fifth line in your answer $$\frac{u^2}{u^2+5}=\frac{u^2+5-5}{u^2+5}=\frac{u^2+5}{u^2+5}-\frac{5}{u^2+5}=1-\frac{5}{u^2+5}$$

Comment: So the main reason for adding the +5 and the -5 is so that it is like you technically did not add anything because well $5-5=0$ and it still maintains it with just $u^2$ right? But also allows to separate it into two different fractions, if that is so, then why is it that we must make two different fractions?

Comment: Sorry about that but I now see what you meant, the whole point was to simplify that fraction and get rid of it. Ok thank you I understand now.

Answer (score 3):

Try making a substitution of the inside function, that often works better. In this case, for the equation
 $$\int\sqrt{e^t-5}dt$$
make the substitution $u=e^t$, $\,\,du = e^tdt$
 $$=\int\frac{\sqrt{u-5}}{u}du$$
substitute $s = \sqrt{u-5}$, $\,\,ds = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{u-5}}$
 $$=2\int\frac{s^2}{s^2 + 5}ds$$
 $$=2\int\ \bigg(1-\frac{5}{s^2 + 5}\bigg)ds$$
 $$=2\int1\,ds - 10\int \frac{ds}{s^2 + 5}$$
 $$=2s - 2\int \frac{ds}{\frac{s^2}{5} + 1}$$
substitute $p = \frac{s}{\sqrt{5}}$, $\,\,dp = \frac{ds}{\sqrt{5}}$
 $$=2s - 2\sqrt{5}\int \frac{dp}{p^2 + 1}$$
 $$=2s - 2\sqrt{5}\tan^{-1}(p)$$
After a couple back-subtitutions we get
 $$=2\sqrt{e^t - 5} - 2\sqrt{5}\tan^{-1}\bigg(\frac{\sqrt{e^t - 5}}{\sqrt{5}}\bigg) + C$$
I like solving the problem this way as it feels more linear... Instead of trying to find what trick to use you just keep messing with the integral, making it simpler until you notice that you are either near to or in a form you can easily integrate.

Comment: It is given that i must use $u=\sqrt{e^t-5}$

Comment: @CarlosV Alright, I can redo the integral in terms of $u = \sqrt{e^t - 5}$, although the solution is not elegant at all

Comment: @CarlosV Actually, Harish provides an answer the way the question asks below. In the future, you might specify that you have to make a specific u-substitution. I'll continue my answer anyway, for future readers and to show the way I would approach the problem

Comment: Yeah i was about to add it would be the way Harish did it and sorry about that i thought having the __u=__ under the original equation as well was enough but next time i will also specify in text. Thank you anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Note that formally we have $u = \sqrt{e^{t}-5}$ iff $\log(u^{2}+5) = t$,
so
$$
\int_{t} \sqrt{e^{t}-5} = \int_{u = \sqrt{e^{t}-5}}u \cdot D\log(u^{2}+5) = \int_{u} \frac{2u^{2}}{u^{2}+5}. 
$$
Can you continue?